# Alternative definition of support of a measure

Tags: measure-theory

Is there any "intrinsic definition" of support of a measure which does not rely on any topological concept? We've been discussing this in our class, and what we do feel about the support of a measure is that it must be an element of the sigma-algebra which is maximal in the sense that it is the biggest set whose measure is positive.

Is it possible to define an "intrinsic definition" of support of a measure function? Why do mathematicians rely it on a topological notion?